# Django - 'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'künstler_set'

Tags: django, database, django-models

I have a relation between an artist and images. I want to show a single artist and his related images. I created two models for artist and image. Inside the image class I made a ForeignKey to artist:

```
class Artist(models.Model):
    profilepic  = models.ImageField( blank=True)
    surname     = models.CharField(max_length=120)

class Image(models.Model):
    image     = models.ImageField()
    relArtist    = models.ForeignKey(Artist, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
```

inside my views.py I tried to get the artist by ID (primaryKey) which is working perfectly but it didn't work with the images.

```
def artistSingle(request, pk):
    artist = Artist.objects.filter(id=pk)
    images = artist.relArtist_set.all()

    return render(request, 'artists/artistSingle.html', {
        'artist': artist,
        'images': images,
    })
```

If I run the code it throws an error:
**'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'relArtist_set'**
I dont know how to get the images which rely to the artist. Does someone have a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should first get your artist with [get()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/queries/#retrieving-a-single-object-with-get) method ( filter returns QuerySet)

```
artist = Artist.objects.get(id=pk)
```

You should use get and not filter, filter returns QuerySet and it is meant to return multiple artist objects) and your actual artist in this case would be `artist = Artist.objects.filter(id=pk)[0]`

Default is relatedmodelname_set as [documented](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/queries/#related-objects) so:

```
images = artist.image_set.all()
```

It can be set to different value by using related_name attribute

```
relArtist    = models.ForeignKey(Artist, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL related_name='images')

images = artist.images.all()
```

Comment: I tried both but its not working, as I add related_name="artistImage" it throws same error: 'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'artistImage'. I migrate the DB

Comment: You should use get and not filter, filter returns QuerySet artist objects) and your actual artist would be artist = Artist.objects.filter(id=pk)[0], while get() returns actual object

Answer (score 0):

`images = Image.objects.filter(relArtist=artist)`

Normally, the Artist would not be aware of any images tied to it, so you should check for the images whose artist match the one you have.
However, Django provides a Manager to reverse the foreign key functionality, making the Artist aware of the images tied to it.
`images = artist.image_set.all()`

Answer (score -1):

Please try the following one. It will resolve your problem.

```
def artistSingle(request, pk):
    artist_queryset = Artist.objects.filter(id=pk)
    artist = artist_queryset.first() if artist_queryset.first() else None
    try:
        images = artist.image_set.all()
    except Exception as exp:
        images = []

    return render(request=request, template_name='artists/artistSingle.html', context={
        'artist': artist,
        'images': images,
    })
```

Comment: never set object to none also there is no need to get first() as it is assumed that pk is unique so get() is enough also rather use https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/http/shortcuts/#get-object-or-404 than showing page without actual author